# Waiting for a method/process to yield - Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have created a spring Webflux application. In this application, we are trying to retrieve a record from the DB and then use that record to complete further processing.

I have wrapped my `repository.get()` method within a `Mono` like below:

**find()**

```
@NotNull
  private Mono<RuntimeCallbackDetails> find(DealsFulfilmentCallback callback, DealsFulfilmentCallbackStatus status) {
    String entityId = callback.getEntityId();
    String itemId = callback.getItemId();
    String type = getCallbackType(callback.getEntityId());
    Long fulfilmentId = Optional.ofNullable(callback.getFId()).orElse(-1L);

    return fulfilmentAcknowledgementService.findFulfilmentAcknowledgement(entityId, itemId, fulfilmentId, type)
        .map(acknowledgement -> {
          validationService.validate(acknowledgement, CALLBACK);
          return RuntimeCallbackDetails.from(callback, acknowledgement, status);
        })
        .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Error while retrieving fulfilment acknowledgement for callback: ", throwable))
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just(RuntimeCallbackDetails.from(callback, status))));
  }
```

**FulfilmentAcknowledgementService.findFulfilmentAcknowledgement()**

```
@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
  public Mono<FulfilmentAcknowledgement> findFulfilmentAcknowledgement(String entityId, String itemId, Long fulfilmentId, String type) {
    return Mono.justOrEmpty(fulfilmentAcknowledgementRepository.findFulfilmentAcknowledgement(entityId, itemId, fulfilmentId, type));
  }
```

Now the challenge here is that the flow does not even wait for the `find` method to execute and return the record. It moves on and since nothing is retrieved, an empty response is propagated downstream. How do I make this `find` method execute the query and return the `Mono` based on this retrieved element?

Comment: What's `fulfilmentAcknowledgementRepository.findFulfilmentAcknowledgement` doing?

Comment: @curiousdev It is fetching a record from RDS.